# How to close all activity before launch new activity from AppWidgetProvider android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, back-stack

Hi I want to close all activity before launch new activity from AppWidgetProvider. I'm not having idea to do this. could you please suggest me any idea to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `finishAffinity()` method (from `Activity`, [doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())). launch dummy invisible/transparent `Activity`, `finishAffinity` all `Activity`ies and `startActivity` with proper `Intent`

there are also some flags for `Intent`s which should clear your `Activity` backstack, but it depends on declared `launchMode` in Manifest. you may check these

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

or

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check and let you know.

Comment: I have fixed my problem. Thank you so much